# How to use Swagger for Devops Project in VS2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, devops

I am new to Devops. I just need to confirm can we use swagger for the webapi project in devops VS2017. I think there might be some type of extension for using swagger in the current devops project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Sharma, we can use swagger for the webapi project in devops VS2017. Here we can use Swashbuckle.Core.Extension for using swagger with the help of Manage Nuget Packages.